# Find $F(x)=\int_{x^2}^{e^x} \cos (t^3) \ dt $

Tags: integration, functions

If $$F(x)=\int_{x^2}^{e^x} \cos (t^3) \ dt $$

Find $$\int F(x) dx$$

I tried to find $$\int \cos (t^3) \ dt $$ but it is not success !

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not to find $F'(x)$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes...I don't believe it is possible to integrate easily. Here is what Wolfram gives: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28t%5E3%29+with+respect+to+t&dataset=

Comment: OK, please update the question.  My answer to the updated question is below.

Comment: edited just now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  One is that 
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)
$$
where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.  The other part says that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)
$$
This is the one that's relevant here.

Combining with the Chain Rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{h(x)} f(t)\,dt = f(h(x))h'(x)
$$
Finally,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t)\,dt = f(h(x))h'(x) - f(g(x))g'(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(t)$ be an anti-derivative of $\cos(t^3)$, this exists by fundamental theorem. Thus, we know that $G'(t) = \cos(t^3)$. Thus, 
$$ F(x) = \int_{x^2}^{e^x} \cos(t^3) ~ dt = G(t) \bigg|_{x^2}^{e^x} = G(e^x) - G(x^2) $$
Now you can compute $F'(x)$.